# Unable to SSH into VM from Windows 10 (was working before)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I'm running a Ubuntu 14 VM in Oracle Virtual Box on my host Windows 10 machine for a university assignment which runs mininet. Everything was working well until one day I woke up and tried to ssh into the VM and it logs me in (shows the welcome message) but the prompt does not show. Like it's just a flashing line which indicates I can type but if I press enter or anything my computer makes a beep sound and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> ends it.

I ssh using

```
ssh user@ip
```

and it was working perfectly literally a day before and I cannot recall making any changes that would ruin it. I've uninstalled the VM images and re-imported a fresh version, I've re-installed virtual box, and tried various settings inside the VM to get it to work but to no avail. I can ssh into the VM using PuTTy just fine but I need to use Visual Studio and it doesn't support PuTTy. I feel that the problem is with my host machine but I cannot figure out what it is.

Any tips on what I can do to try and fix it?

UPDATE with the -v command below. The connection closed after I manually closed it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The welcome message shows but then nothing after that just the cursor blinking.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ssh -v  cs551@192.168.56.10
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for 192.168.56.10
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.10 [192.168.56.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.56.10:22 as 'cs551'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:wDmGnoAN/7DHHH1OTiFsKC3l4v5PYvxOm659KKLCDwk
debug1: Host '192.168.56.10' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:iMnIfpXDKQgmDCnJSUpBS1x4uOM3gXOa888wrKwkLDI C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\HP/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
cs551@192.168.56.10's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.56.10 ([192.168.56.10]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: console doesn't support the ansi parsing
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-53-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Tue Feb 16 06:16:59 2021 from 192.168.56.1

oot
eu: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.56.10 closed.
Transferred: sent 2212, received 2552 bytes, in 64.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 34.2, received 39.5
debug1: Exit status 0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: 1. Please check you have allotted sufficient storage space and memory to the VM. 2. Why Ubuntu 14 why not 20?

Comment: So if I'm reading correctly, the PuTTY SSH client works, but a different SSH client on Windows does not?

Comment: @raghu it's for an assignment so I don't have the choice

Comment: @steeldriver yes you are right. I am using OpenSSH and it is not working but PuTTy is working fine

Comment: try running `ssh -v user@ip` (`-v` is the verbose flag, you can add more (up to `-v -v -v -v`).. This may give you some idea of where ssh is hanging.

Comment: @BartonChittenden I've added the output in the post above. I was unable to really figure anything out from that, do you spot anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Firstly, you can re-configure SSH server by running the following command on Linux box:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

If above command fails, simply regenerate SSH keys on the Linux box:

```
$ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa
```

(2) Secondly, you opened PowerShell (PS) as admin. You need to open PS as a regular user, where your existing SSH env variables are, then SSH will work again.

(3) Thirdly, get rid of the old SSH public keys from your Windows machine

```
$ ssh-keygen -R 192.168.56.10
```

(4) Then finally you can SSH as per normal.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I've done all the steps you've mentioned above and unfortunately I am still facing the same issue. The -v command output is also still the same. Any other ideas of what I can try?

Comment: Try using CMD instead of PS

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 32bit?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue using cmd and no I am on Windows 10. Everything was working fine a day ago on this exact set up but for apparently no reason at all this issue has popped up

Comment: The log output interestingly shows "OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1"

Comment: I installed OpenSSH by going into Apps & Features -> Optional Features -> Add Feature. I've tried re-installing OpenSSH Client and OpenSSH server as well although I was facing issues installing them initially as the installation would fail. After installing the latest Windows update I was able to install them. Could the OpenSSH installation be an issue?

Comment: Since you are on Windows 10, try to enable Windows Subsytem Linux (WSL), then reboot your system. Then SSH from the Linux subsystem.

Comment: I was able to successfully ssh using the linux subsystem. I'm confused now... is this a problem with my OpenSSH installation in windows 10? My main task is basically to be able to use VS code in my windows machine to work on files in my VM

Comment: I just tried to SSH using the Windows 10 Powershell and I was able to!! It started working after I connected once using the linux subsystem. I'm not sure what was wrong or how the problem was fixed but I want to thank you for taking time out to help me!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. If you look at the error logs, you will see that env variables were changed. You can tell by "no such file or directory" in the error messages that you posted earlier. I believe the windows subsystem restored the env variables back to normal.